# Does a normally-mindless creature get the standard one feat if it gains an INT rating?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, monsters

A Greensting Scorpion is a vermin with 1 HD, and it is mindless (INT —). The monster creation rules don't allow a mindless creature to get the usual extra feat that all other creatures with 1 HD do. But if this scorpion becomes a familiar and it loses its mindless status, it will have at least INT 6. Does it gain its previously-negated feat slot?

Comment: For what it's worth, here's [James Jacobs stating that all ability score increases apply everything retroactively](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kpru?Int-and-Skills#10). Nevermind figuring out how retroactive increases to *damage* work. "So now my Str is 20, so I would have done 1 more point of damage per hit on that BBEG, downing him 1 round early, which means Magic Mike never died in the first place!" (I hope you see why I chose not to use this post to build an answer upon)

Answer (score 3):

From [D20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar):

> It retains the appearance, Hit Dice, base attack bonus, base save bonuses, skills, **and feats** of the normal animal it once was [...]

and further down,

> *Familiar Basics*
>
> Use the basic statistics for a creature of the familiar's kind, but with the following changes.
>
> Hit Dice: [...]
>
> Hit Points: [...]
>
> Attacks: [...]
>
> Saving Throws: [...]
>
> Skills: [...]

Note no mention of feats there.

There is a box below labelled *FYI: Feats for Animal Companions & Familiars*. Clicking through to any of the listed feat descriptions gives you the following info:

> Special: Feats that are meant for familiars can be switched out for **a familiar's default feats** (as listed in the familiar's statistics) if the familiar meets the prerequisites. Such feat replacements must be made when the PC first acquires a new familiar, and like all new feats from supplemental sources the new feats should be approved by the GM before being integrated into play.

So, if a familiar's base creature type has feats, these may be swapped out (with GM permission), but they do not gain more.

In the specific case of the [Greensting Scorpion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/vermin/scorpion/scorpion-greensting) you mention, it has one feat: Weapon Finesse. So, with GM permission, you may be able to swap it out.